# pyplot image won't animate

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I'm having a problem with trying to create a simple image animation with pyplot and matplotlib.animation. The animation function is a member function of a class I am developing. I originally had a crude animation working by re-drawing images and calling plt.pause(). I thought that it would run smoother when I used matplotlib.animation so I re-modeled the new animation after this example code http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/dynamic_image2.html. I ran that example and it works as expected for me.

When I run this function, it doesn't return any errors. It opens two figures with axes scaled to my image size (as expected) but neither of them animate.

```
def simulate(self):
    fig = plt.figure()
    ims = []

    for i in range(len(self.bright1)):
        data = np.zeros((1,self.arsize,3),np.uint8)
        data[0,:,0] = 140*bigunpackbits(self.bright1[i],self.arsize)
        data[0,:,1] = 140*bigunpackbits(self.bright1[i],self.arsize)
        data[0,:,2] = 140*bigunpackbits(self.bright1[i],self.arsize)
        im = plt.imshow(data)
        ims.append([im])

    animation.ArtistAnimation(fig,ims,interval=50,blit=True,repeat_delay=1000)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: The problem is that you need to return the animation object and keep a reference to it.  There is an issue on gh and I think we updated the docs for 1.4.0.

Comment: The github issue is [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/1656)

Comment: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3105 is a related issue dealing with call-backs.  Slightly different, but the same general idea applies

Comment: I am sure I have answered this question on SO before, but am having issues finding them...

Comment: Holding the animation object fixed it, thanks!

Comment: While I'm here, can anyone also tell me why it creates two figures? One of them doesn't do anything and would be nice if it went away.