# Issue with FuncAnimation: Animation in Matplotlib based on an Event

Tags: python, arrays, animation, numpy, matplotlib

This is a simple question about Matplotlib's FuncAnimation method. I've tried everything and can't get it to work!

I'm writing a code that allows the user to select a horizontal line on an im show plot so that they can see the evaluation of an array corresponding to each of the pixels (y-axis) where each point corresponds to another predetermined numpy array. The x- array (set of x-values is labelled "lambda_array" of length 1024 and the y values are labelled "intensity_shaped" and are in a [10][256][1024] shaped array, or simply [y][x][values]. Essentially I would like the animation to iterate over intensity_shaped[y][x+i][2:values] with i being the iterator.

This question is not concerned with the horizontal line or the event handling, I simply can't get the  'FuncAnimation' method to function properly... it creates a new window, but there's nothing in it. I have identified three possible hypotheses:1) I'm probably misssing an easy step for the function to work 2) there is some kind of incompatibility with numpy arrays 3)I need to redraw it using 'plt.draw' which I'm not doing...

This should be relatively straight forward for someone who knows how to animate with Matplotlib!!!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

plt.ion()

fig_anim = plt.figure("Animation")
graph, = plt.plot([],[], '-r')

def init_graph():
    graph.set_data((lambda_array), intensity_shaped[5][50][2:]) #<- these are both numpy arrays.
    return graph,


def animate(k):
    graph.set_ydata(intensity_shaped[5][50+k][2:])
    return graph,

def animate_func():
    anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig_anim,animate,
                             init_func=init_graph,
                             frames =100, interval = 50) 
    plt.draw()
    return anim

animate_func()    #<- this doens't work alone

animation.FuncAnimation(fig_anim,animate,               #<- this doesn't help
                             init_func=init_graph,
                             frames =100, interval = 50) 

plt.show()
```

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25716776/pyplot-image-wont-animate  Hold on to a ref to `anim` so that the timers which run the animation don't get garbage collected.

Comment: @tcaswell i added: `anim = animate_func()` but it still doesnt work.

Comment: Then I tried `anim = animate.FuncAnimation.....` the long call and it still didn't work